# Interesting recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

The other day I was playing around with some recursive functions, and I made a simple algorithm like this:

```
int f(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return f(f(n-1)-1) * n;
}
```

What is interesting is that it works for f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3) & f(4) but not matter what language or compiler I try it in, nothing seems to be able to complete f(5) without causing a stack overflow.

My question is how / where could I run this to find the solution to f(5) and also what might be the big-O complexity of a function like this?

The first couple results are 1,1,2,3,8...

Comment: Plugging in `f(5)` requires you to compute `f(f(4) - 1) = f(7)` etc. The computation does not terminate.

Comment: ^ditto. And there is no meaning of computational complexity of a non-computable problem.

Comment: Tried memorization too @Dukeling no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with this function is that it does not guarantee the recursion will stop. It would be OK if the argument passed to the recursive call of `f` would be smaller than *n* (and >= 0), but for n >= 4, this is no longer the case. `f(4) = 8`, and so when calculating `f(5)`, you make a recursive call of `f` with argument `f(4)-1`, which is 7. So where you had *n* = 5, now you call it with *n* = 7, which is not reducing the problem, but making it bigger. This just explodes further: for determining `f(7)`, you need `f(6)`, and for `f(6)` you need `f(5)`, but that is the value we are looking for, so this is like running in circles for ever and ever.

For this reason, `f(5)` is undefined. The recursive form cannot be reduced to *solve* `f`, so `f` is not correctly defined.

Comment: Ah thank you for that, so even if I had an arbitrarily large stack it would never get smaller?

Comment: Also why does it blow up at 4, that seems pretty random?

Comment: It is the first value for which `f(n) > n`. And yes, the recursion would go on for ever. Even with an infinite stack (which does not exist), you would not be able to get an answer, since `f(5)` needs `f(7)`, which needs `f(6)`, which neeeds `f(5)`, ... but that is what we are looking for, so we are running in circles.

Comment: wait f(4) = 8 and 8 > 4

Comment: Should be that it's the first value for which `f(n-1)-1 > n`.